# Assassins Creed 2 undo a viewpoint sync

Tags: xbox-360, assassins-creed-2

In Monteriggioni one of the missions is to synchronize the viewpoint at the top of the villa. Me being impatient when it comes to having no mini-map, already synchronized this viewpoint before the mission was even available. Now, in-mission, I go back to the viewpoint, and of course get no option to sync, but the mission does not progress either. The yellow marker on the map is exactly where the viewpoint is and I can't continue, presumably because the viewpoint is already synced. Does anybody know how I can un-sync a viewpoint? Or is there any other way to force progression at this point? Do I really have to start again?

Comment: Have you tried triggering the camera sequence (pressing E, I believe) regardless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was just a glitch in that particular play through. After turning my Xbox off and starting it up again, the objective was glowing like it should and it was interact-able. Thanks anyway to FEichinger.